# java memory allocation for local variables

Tags: java, memory, jtextpane

I have a java application which uses a **SerialPortEvent** which will be called continously ,

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {

    if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int length = input.available();
            byte[] array = new byte[length];
            int numBytes = input.read(array);
.......
......
}
```

i print the **array** variable contents in a text pane.
I have a scenario in which the event will be called continuosly , it makes the the windows Memory(private Working set) increase gradually and doesn't stop.

My question is, whether creating new **variables** every time the event is called makes use of memory??

i simply get contents and print it in JTextpane and nothing else.

Comment: Do not rely on InputStream.available(). This is only an estimation.

Comment: These variables will accumulate until java decides to execute garbage collection.

Comment: None of the code you have show will memory leak.  data on the stack is freed as soon as you return from the method,  heap is freed when you need more heap.  This can mean the heap rises alarmingly, but as soon as you run out it frees up memory.  You should look at how much memory is used after a full collection to see how much is truly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating variables as such doesn't create a memory leak. The leak happens when you keep a reference to a local variable somewhere.

My guess is that you eventually append the content of `sBuilder` to the `JTextpane` which of course keeps the content around permanently.

The solution is to check the length of the `JTextpane` (number of lines). If there are too many, then remove some. That way, you always keep, say, 1000 lines in memory and the consumption will be in check.

Related:

- [Java Garbage Collection Basics](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)
- [Quick introduction to Java Garbage Collector (JVM GC)](http://de.slideshare.net/MarcosGarcia10/quick-introduction-to-java-garbage-collector-jvm-gc)
- [How Garbage Collection works in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)

Comment: Hi .. got a doubt while checking it.. While removing the extra lines from a JtextPane the memory of the removed line will be released during GC?

Comment: I have limited the lines as you told and checked for heap usage and it reduced than before.. But still what i dont understand is, even after limiting the lines, windows Memory(private Working set) keeps on increasing for the application's process. What might be the reason for it?

Comment: I suggest that read up on how the garbage collection works: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html and http://de.slideshare.net/MarcosGarcia10/quick-introduction-to-java-garbage-collector-jvm-gc

Comment: There are about 15000000 reasons why your application memory keeps growing. Use a profiler to find out which one.

Answer (score 0):

Of course creating new variables will increase the memory used by your program BUT unless you are keeping strong references to them (hard to tell by just reading the few lines of code you posted) this memory should be released at the next garbage collecting cycle. Now, I'm not a java guru, and I do not know how JTextPane works under the hood but if it keeps the whole string in memory while displaying it (most probably) I would expect the memory necessary for that string to continuously increase each time I add content to it. But if the increase you are seeing is significantly more than the amount of bytes you write in the text pane, I would look around for strong references that are kept around (or circular references). Mind that you can always hint the garbage collector to run by calling `System.gc()` but this is just a hint to the collector and it is up to it, whether to run or not.