# Converting byte[] to String with new Operator(performance)

Tags: java, string, memory, arrays

Based on the below question,

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753342/java-memory-allocation-for-local-variables`

I use SerialPortEvent to read data from serial port,

```
public String logtext = ""; 
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {

if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
    try {
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int length = input.available();
        byte[] array = new byte[length];
        int numBytes = input.read(array);
        for (byte b : array) {
          logText = new String(new byte[] {b});                 
          sBuilder.append(logText);
        }
       //Finally i append the StringBuilder to JtextPane
       .......
       ......
        }
```

Creating **new String()** every time the serialEvent is called it will create new instance every time which will increase the memory usage.. In certain scenario this serialEvent will be called every second.

Is there any other efficient way to do this with out using new operator??

Please help

Comment: Read the documentation for String, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do this one byte at a time.  I would just do all the bytes at once.

```
int length = input.available();
byte[] array = new byte[length];
String logText = new String(array, 0); // assume ISO-8859-1 encoding
```

Comment: Yes i would have did it , but in my byte array i have ASCII values of new line and bell ascii..In order to remove it i did like this if byte array content equal to ascii don show in JtextPane. Is there any way i can remove ascii from the String by using the code which you have mentioned.